# Parameter from URL not available on the controller

Tags: laravel

This may turn out to be a stupid question, but somehow, $request->input() returns an empty array, despite parameters being available in URL.

The route seems to be correct:

```
Route::get('/fotos/visualizar/{id}', 'FotosController@visualizar');
```

But still `$request->input() returns an empty array`, and `$request->input('id') returns null`.

Another route configured exactly the same works perfectly.

Is there anything I could be missing, or some log I can check that I haven't learned about yet?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass id on your controller like visualizar(Request $request, $id). Your get your url parameter in $id

Comment: That wasn't needed on another controller, and I don't think I've ran across getting parameters like that in the documentation (yet).

Comment: can you show me your visualizar method inside FotosController ?

Comment: I didn't even get around to write it, since I was still trying to figure out how to get uploaded photos from storage. All I had was `public function visualizar(Request $request) { dd($request->input();}`, to check that nothing else had been interfering.

Comment: you cannot get URL parameter this way.  try this only the way

    public function visualizar(Request $request, $id) { 
      dd($id);
    }